# How this code using the wavread function works in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have some problems understanding this code from another question (I can't comment on that answer because I'm new and I don't have enough reputation).

The code is this:

```
[song, fs] = wavread('C:\Path of My File\song.wav');
song = song(1:fs*10);
spectrogram(song, windowSize, windowOverlap, freqRange, fs, 'yaxis');
```

I don't know what the second line of code does. Can someone explain it? Does it affect the output of the spectrogram?

My code is:

```
[song, fs] = wavread('C:\Users\Iván\Downloads\Kawai-K3-Strings-C5.wav');
song = song(1:fs*5); //(first this line was ...(1:fs*10) but didnt work. why? i would like to know.
spectrogram(song, 256, [], [], fs, 'xaxis');
```

Answer (score 1):

The second line of code is extracting a sample of the song's time series of length 10 times the sampling frequency in Hertz.

You should first check that there are enough samples in the song by checking the length of the song using

> songlength = numel(song)/fs

If there are not enough samples to cover 10 times the sample frequency, use a shorter multiplier.

The spectrogram is then being computed on that sample, rather than the whole song.

You'll need to consult the Matlab documentation on spectrogram to select the call options to accomplish  useful signal processing goals, depending on what you want to do.